# Flex: given Class object, get the name of the class it represents

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

In Flex, say I have a Class object.  How do I get a string for the class it represents?

e.g.:

```
var clazz:Class= String;
trace(clazz);  // this gives "[class String]" but what I want is "String"
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`flash.utils::getQualifiedClassName` is the function you are looking for ... ;)

greetz

back2dos

Comment: getQualifiedClassName(clazz) returns "String". I expected it to return "Class"!

Comment: flash.utils::getDefinitionByName() takes a string and returns a Class.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to know all there is about a class, use [**describeType**](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType()). Related, you might find useful [getDefinition](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html#getDefinition()) and [getDefinitionByName](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName()).

describeType return all the details in an XML object. If you're looking just for the name,
try something like:

```
trace(describeType(String).@name);
```

This is general actionscript. It has no dependency on the flex framework. 
Goodluck.

Comment: This works, but note that it is significantly slower than getQualifiedClassName()

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple as2 code I've done that allows you to get the base class and the current class as a string :

If current class is empty, this is a base class

```
public function ObjectContructor(){
  var _construct:String;
  var _instance:String;
  for(var s:String in _global){
    if(this.constructor == _global[s])_construct = s;
    if(this instanceof _global[s] && this.constructor != _global[s])_instance = s;
  }
  trace("base class : " +_construct);
  trace("Current class : " + _instance);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Does this work?

```
trace(clazz.toString());
```

Comment: As I said, clazz.toString() returns "[class String]"